# Virtual machine can't reach XAMPP Correctly

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I have set up an xampp server with multiple websites on my windows 10 machine 
(each of them have a own index.php file).
(The machine internal IP:192.168.1.133).

as picture below:

[image]

This is how my **C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts** file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost<br>
127.0.0.1    mydevsite1.com<br>
127.0.0.1    mydevsite2.com<br>
127.0.0.1    mydevsite3.com<br>
127.0.0.1    mydevsite4.com<br>
127.0.0.1    mydevsite5.com<br>
```

I have also set up an **Oracle virtual machine** with network type:
**Bridged Adapter** as below:

[image]


From my virtual machine I can navigate to 192.168.1.133

(the physical machine)

see picture below:

[image]

that works flawless.

though.... now when I try to navigate to

```
 mydevsite1.com
```

then I get following error as below:

[image]

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you using a virtual machine to access the xampp server on your physical machine ? Just curious. Anyway, your virtual machine does not seem to know what to lookup, when you are trying to reach `www.mydevsite1.com`. Did you try to edit the host file on your virtual machine just like you did with the physical machine and add e.g. `192.168.1.133  mydevsite1.com` ? Do you really have these `<br>` tags in your host file on the physical machine or did you put them there to add linebreaks to this post?

Comment: The VM doesn't use the hosts file of the host. If it doesn't find the entry in its own hosts file, it will perform a DNS lookup with the nameserver IP assigned to it via DHCP (or manually if static configuration was used).

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: @DanielElmnas Did you try to edit the host file on the virtual machine ?

Comment: No I haven't edited the Host file in the Vmware.

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in the comments, the VM guest will not use the host computer's `hosts` file, even when the adapter is bridged. You should try altering the `hosts` file on the virtual machine with something similar to the following:

*ex. VM `hosts` file*

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
192.168.1.133    mydevsite1.com
192.168.1.133    mydevsite2.com
192.168.1.133    mydevsite3.com
192.168.1.133    mydevsite4.com
192.168.1.133    mydevsite5.com
```

Also, notice in your screenshot how `www` is added automatically to the URL. Even if your XAMPP installation is correctly configured to resolve `www` versions of the given domains (which you should double-check), these URLs are considered separately for DNS purposes.  So you should have entries for those versions as well:

*ex. VM `hosts` file (cont.)*

```
192.168.1.133    www.mydevsite1.com
192.168.1.133    www.mydevsite2.com
192.168.1.133    www.mydevsite3.com
192.168.1.133    www.mydevsite4.com
192.168.1.133    www.mydevsite5.com
```

---

As a side note, since you are doing all this stuff with the `hosts` file of each computer, it might be worth your time to consider setting up a small, local DNS server. In theory (depending on a number of factors) this could be a simpler option than modifying the `hosts` file for every device you wish to connect to your sites.

Comment: I have tested this same result as before. Also it feels a bit unnecessary to set us a dns-server but I will investigate more if you don't have any more suggestions?

Comment: I might look at your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and make sure "files" appears as the first entry on the `hosts:` line for that file. If you are running `nscd` (which provides a cache for the most common name service requests) you may have to restart that (e.g. something like "sudo service nscd restart") after editing nsswitch.conf. If you don't know if you have `nscd` you can do "ps ax | grep nscd" or similar. Otherwise, BIND (or another DNS server) would likely be your next step. [This article has an overview of running BIND on Kali](https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/07/22/kalilinux-2017-1-bind-en/).