# VMware can't connect to Xampp localhost

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, kali-linux, localhost, xampp

### Problem

I'm running Windows 10 on my physical computer. Xampp is running in it. The configurations are default 127.0.0.1 80, 443.

I'm running Kali Linux on VMware Workstation(Latest) but noncommercial. Firefox ESR installed there in default.

When I browse `http://localhost` from FireFox ESR it says it can't reach. I know I can install Xampp in Linux but I don't want for some reasons. **How do I connect to my localhost server of Xampp from Kali in VMware?**

### Host Configurations

***Content of `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`***

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

***Content of `/etc/hosts` in Kali***

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 kali kali

192.168.137.129 localhost
......  ......
```

***Content of `/etc/resolv.conf` in Kali***

```
nameserver 192.168.137.129
```

### Research

Before asking this question I've did some research over it. I've googled this question in same query and tried those solutions. None of these worked for me.

[Is it possible to access the Xampp on VMware Workstation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24256/is-it-possible-to-access-the-xampp-on-vmware-workstation)

[How to access a virtual host created by Xampp from Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396935/how-to-access-a-virtual-host-created-by-xampp-from-virtual-machine)

[Virtual Machine can't reach Xampp Correctly](https://superuser.com/questions/1293720/virtual-machine-cant-reach-xampp-correctly)

[How do I access guest "localhost" server from Host?](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/338791)

[How do I access localhost from VMware](https://superuser.com/questions/307001/how-do-i-access-localhost-from-vmware)

Also, tried others from Google search. `ipconfig` and `ifconfig` isn't working on both the machines which was mentioned on solutions.

I've browsed `http://localhost` `http://127.0.0.1` `http://127.0.1.1` `http://192.168.137.129`. Tried with `NAT` and `Bridged` both.

Comment: If you type the local IP address of the physical machine hosting XAMPP into the browser on that same machine (not the VM), is XAMPP available?

Comment: @Anaksunaman don't know. But, I can access Xampp by `http://localhost` and `http://127.0.0.1` only.